# how to use row index as dataset index using c#.net

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am newbie to c# I am working on project i am trying to loop through data table containing distinct values
 and my database has song id like:1,2,3,4,6,8,9,10
but dataset takes this values as 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 respectively... thanks

```
String sql = "select  title, song_id from up_song where Song_type='Mp3 Tracks' ";
    adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cn);
    ds = new DataSet();

    adpt.Fill(ds, "title");
    var maxvalue = ds.Tables["title"].AsEnumerable().Max(x => x.Field<int>("song_id"));
    var minvalue = ds.Tables["title"].AsEnumerable().Min(x => x.Field<int>("song_id"));
    for (i =maxvalue; i >= minvalue; --i)
        {
            try
            {
                hyperlink[i] = new HyperLink();
                hyperlink[i].ID = "hyperlink" + i;
                hyperlink[i].Text = ds.Tables["title"].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                hyperlink[i].NavigateUrl = "Downloadpage.aspx";
                hyperlink[i].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                Panel1.Controls.Add(hyperlink[i]);
                Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
                HttpCookie coo = new HttpCookie("song");
                coo["sogtit"] = ds.Tables["title"].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                Response.Cookies.Add(coo);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: have you tried to set the minvalue = minvalue + 1 before the for loop?

Comment: I would suggest changing to a foreach loop instead :D makes it easier to read.

Comment: but if i use foreach loop how i can access latest added row from database

Answer (score 2):

You are using the loop variable to acess the rows in the `DataTable` here:

```
coo["sogtit"] = ds.Tables["title"].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
```

But the variable is initialized from the `min` and `max` ID values of your `song_id`.

I don't know why you need these values at all, why don't you loop the `DataRows`:

```
foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables["title"].Rows)
{
    // ...
    int songID = row.Field<int>("song_id")
    Hyperlink hl = new HyperLink(); // you don't need the array of hyperlinks neither
    hl.ID = "hyperlink" + songID;
    string title = row.Field<string>("title);
    hl.Text = title;
    coo["sogtit"] = title;
    Panel1.Controls.Add(hl);
    // ...
}
```

**Update**

> i want to access those latest upload song so i use for loop and index
>   as min and max values. i mean want to access latest uploaded minimum 6
>   song

You could use Linq to get the last 6 uploaded songs:

```
var last6Uploaded = ds.Tables["title"].AsEnumerable()
    .OrderByDescending(r => r.Field<int>("song_id"))
    .Take(6);

foreach(DataRow row in last6Uploaded)
{
    // ...
}
```

Note that you should use a `DateTime` field instead of the primary-key.

Comment: thank you,your code really help me i am working on musicsite and its database contains titles that i want to display as hyperlinks so i want to access those latest upload song so i use for loop and index as min and max values. i mean want to access latest uploaded minimum 6 song pls help.

Comment: here in one page i display hyperlinks when user click on this one link  i want to display on another page name of link. but my problem is coo["songtit"]=title takes the last value of dataset?? so how transfer data between two html page??

Answer (score 0):

The array index (`i`) and the value of song_id *should* have nothing to do with each other. What if your song_id started at 1000? Or if your database indexed by song_id in descending order?

Comment: actuly i am working on musicsite and its database contains titles that i want to display in hyperlinks so i want to access those latest upload song so i use for loop and index has min and max values but my code is not working here it display only those value that match with song id.